# Show button over ar.js content

Tags: javascript, html, css, aframe, ar.js

I'm wondering how it would be possible to show html content inside an ar.js experience. Currently I am trying to add a button to the top of the webpage, over the ar.js but for some reason, my button remains hidden. I'm wondering how I can get the button to show at the top of my screen. Ive tried fixing the position and using css but the button remains hidden behind the ar.js.

Current code:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<button>Inverse</button>

<body>
    <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;'>
        <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5;'></a-box>
        <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

The css:

```
.inversed {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000000;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

The javascript:

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $("html").toggleClass("inversed");
});
```

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/CreateVR/pen/PoReoLb

Comment: Unclear what the issue is supposed to be, the button in your codepen appears to work fine for me? Clicking it toggles the `inversed` class.

Comment: @CBroe what OS are you on? I see the problem if I allow camera access on IOS.

Comment: Mac OS, Chromium-based browser.

Comment: For some reason the button isn't showing up for me. I've tried it on many devices and none of them seem to be working. As soon as I enable access to my camera, the button disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit with your codepen example and I had the same issue with disappearing html content on allowing camera permission. Nonetheless I was able to make the button visible over the `<a-scene></scene>`.

Just make sure that your button styling contains "top" property with positive px value.

SOLUTION:

```
button {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000000;
  top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Here's an another demo that could inspire you further: https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/rmz694a2/7/

Personally, I would place the html content, that I'm going to show over ar.js content, in additional div container next to a-scene and style it apprioriately.

Example:

```
<body>
  <div style='position: fixed; top: 10px; text-align: start; z-index: 10;'>
    <button>Inverse</button>
  </div>
  <a-scene>
    <!-- the rest of the ar.js code -->
  <a-scene>
</body>
```